# R Extract and get the corresponding Numeric values of a string

Tags: r, function, extract

Need help looking for a function to extract and get values of the requested string separated by "-"

**data:**

```
x <- c("AA-AA/BB-11/CC-22/dd-1", "AA-AA/BB-33/CC-331")
```

**desired output:**

```
BB should get vector of (11, 33)

CC should get vector of (22, 331)
```

Comment: use a regular expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use stringr for the task:

```
library(stringr)
x <- c("AA-AA/BB-11/CC-22/dd-1", "AA-AA/BB-33/CC-331")
BB <- as.numeric(str_match(x, "/BB-([0-9]+)")[, 2])
CC <- as.numeric(str_match(x, "/CC-([0-9]+)")[, 2])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do some trickery using `chartr` to change your split characters, and then feed it into `read.table`:

```
tmp <- read.table(text=chartr("-/", " \n", x), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

#  V1  V2
#1 AA  AA
#2 BB  11
#3 CC  22
#4 dd   1
#5 AA  AA
#6 BB  33
#7 CC 331
```

If you strictly need separate vectors:

```
split(tmp$V2, tmp$V1)

#$AA
#[1] "AA" "AA"
#
#$BB
#[1] "11" "33"
#
#$CC
#[1] "22"  "331"
#
#$dd
#[1] "1"
```